# Ecommerce Automatic Inventory updates

Tags: xml, database, ftp

Please bear with me as i'm not the most technical of people. We have built a website on the ecommerce platform Prestashop and are dealing with one supplier who provides all information of products, prices, stock availability etc through an FTP server which is updated hourly. The files on these are in XML format.

I am trying to see if there is a solution, middle man software, that will allow me to link these updating files to my website. Does anyone know if any exist or if this is a custom solution we would have to look at getting built? Any help is greatly appreciated. - Lei

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) for these kinds of things, though this does require you to know Java, XML or Scala.

But this is a great middle man tool which can be used to to all sorts of things. I mainly use it to convert one type of XML to another.